# Get visibile controller iWatch

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

I have this situation:

I have an iWatch app that has a root `WKInterfaceController` and when it fires a particular event I present another `WKInterfaceController` in this way:

```
WKInterfaceController * rootC = [WKExtension sharedExtension].rootInterfaceController;
[rootC presentControllerWithName:@"testController" context:nil];
```

My problem is that when it fires a particular event that I catch in `InterfaceController`, I have to show an alert in 'testController'. But from that root controller I can't get the visibile controller (like in iPhone project).

Comment: you have to show alert in root controller ?

Comment: no, I have to show alert in the testController, that its the controller presented by root controller

Comment: It's called Apple Watch...

Comment: what do you mean? @EmilioPelaez

Comment: It's not called an iWatch, it's called an Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get visible controller by using WKExtension property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) WKInterfaceController *visibleInterfaceController;
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/2868459-visibleinterfacecontroller?language=objc